# Django Report Builder - Override Toolbar Header

Tags: css, django, angular

Is there anyway to override the Django Report Builder toolbar header? Ive isoloated it down to this:

span _ngcontent-chv-c159="">Welcome to Django Report Builder  </span

But don't understand how to override it?

I've tried overriding the  elements within the template but it doesn't seem to change anything...good chance I'm way off with my thinking here.